# Updating a map entry by converting it to downcase in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How can I update a value in a Map by taking a value of a key as initial one? Namely, I want to convert a string value to its lower case, something like this:

```
Map.update(m1, "key1", ???, &String.downcase/1)
```

What should be in "???" as it requires initial value?

Comment: If the key is guaranteed to be present, you can use `Map.update!/3`, which doesn't need an initial value: `Map.update!(m1, "key1", &String.downcase/1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that initial value is only used if the key is not present, you can just pass in `nil` as the default value like so:

```
Map.update(m1, "key1", nil, &String.downcase/1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a code to fall back gracefully for cases when there is no such value in the map, use [`Map.get_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#get_and_update/3):

```
Map.get_and_update(m1, "key1", fn 
  current_value when is_binary(current_value) ->
    {current_value, String.downcase(current_value) }
  _ ->
    {current_value, "Conversion error: not a string" }
    # or raise
    # or {current_value, current_value}
end)
```

That way you’ll never end up finding the cause of the application accidental crash on *some* input.

---

If you still want to go the easiest path, it’s safer to pass an empty string instead of `nil`:

```
Map.update(m1, "key1", "", &String.downcase/1)
```

The latter won’t at least throw, it would silently return an empty string on unknown keys.